# how to stop loading on uiwebview in ios?

Tags: ios8

Actually I am loading the login page on uiwebview. After successfully login, it automatically goes to another page but I don't want. I want to stop loading on login page and and I want hit the another url with authentication of login and save the data which will return in response.After that I want to show that data which is in json form, another view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Implement the webview delegate method

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

   // handle the url here and return NO to prevent redirecting for particular url

    return YES;
}
```